# Ansible Tower problems copying .yml config file

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Working in Ansible Tower, I am trying to update the codedeployagent.yml file on a server by copying a new version located in a github repo sub-folder called 'files'. However when I run the template in Ansible Tower, I get the following error (below):

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context
The error appears to be in '/tmp/awx/project/files/codedeployagent.yml': line 2, column 14, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
--
:log_aws_wire: false
             ^ here
```

It's like Ansible Tower is treating the codedeployagent.yml file as an ansible file when I don't want it to do that, I just want to copy the file.
Could it be because the config file is a .yml format, do I need to change that in the source repo? This is my ansible playbook (below). Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

```
---
-
  become: yes
  hosts: all
  remote_user: admin
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: remove original CodeDeploy Agent config
          file:
            path: /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
            state: absent

        - name: copy latest CodeDeploy Agent file
          template:
            dest: /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
            mode: 420
            src: files/codedeployagent.yml
          tags:
            - config
        - name: restart CodeDeploy Agent
          service: name=codedeploy-agent state=restarted

  vars_files:
    - files/codedeployagent.yml
```

Comment: You are loading the file in `vars_file`. ansible does what it is told: parse the file to load the variables inside and make them available to the play. And since your yaml file is not valid, you get an error.

Comment: ok thanks, so I might not need the line

  vars_files:
    - files/codedeployagent.yml

if the config file is already referenced at
src: files/codedeployagent.yml

Comment: that worked thanks very much. I removed 
  vars_files:
    - files/codedeployagent.yml
from the bottom of the ansible playbook & deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to thank @Zeitounator for steering me in the right direction, the following ansible playbook now working nicely

```
---
-
  become: yes
  hosts: all
  remote_user: admin
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: remove original CodeDeploy Agent config
          file:
            path: /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
            state: absent

        - name: copy latest CodeDeploy Agent file
          template:
            dest: /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
            mode: 420
            src: files/codedeployagent.yml
          tags:
            - config
        - name: restart CodeDeploy Agent
          service: name=codedeploy-agent state=restarted
```